# Are Android broadcast Intents guaranteed to be delivered?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

**Background**

I have a background IntentService that is started by the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast and then runs periodically in the background afterwards.

The IntentService sends out broadcast Intents as a result of its operation and which are received by a BroadcastReceiver that is registered in the manifest to handle said broadcast Intents.

**Problem**

I have verified that the Intents are being delivered under normal operation, but it appears as if some of the broadcast Intents are not being delivered right after restarting the device. I am trying to narrow down the different causes of this apparent data loss.

My question is: Are broadcast Intents guaranteed to be delivered once they are sent, or are there cases where they may be lost?

Comment: "The IntentService sends out ordered broadcast Intents during operation and the results are recorded in a SQLite database" -- why? Why not just have the `IntentService` store the results in a database? Is this some other app that is supposed to be receiving the broadcasts? Also note that ordered broadcasts can be cancelled. Beyond that, we would need a [mcve] demonstrating how you are sending the broadcast and how you have your `BroadcastReceiver` registered to receive them.

Comment: They are guaranteed to be delivered, but ordering is not, especially in new versions of android.

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond Do you know of documentation that states this? I cannot seem to find any easily.

Comment: @CommonsWare I removed the SQLite reference because it isn't relevant to the question. Are broadcast Intents guaranteed to be delivered or not?

Comment: I don't think that there is a guarantee documented anywhere. I also fail to see why you are using broadcasts this way. Manifest-registered receivers, and their corresponding broadcasts, always involve IPC. Just do the work in the `IntentService` and get rid of the broadcasts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think broadcast are guaranteed to be delivered. I haven't found any info about that. I think you should prepare some queue (or cache) for storing elements during configuration change and send them once broadcast receiver is registered. Alternatively you can check some third party libraries, like EventBus with its "sticky events".

Best of luck!